# Breaking up a numerical string in java

Tags: java, string

I have to break up a string that would consist of 6 numbers (MMCCFU) where MM refers to the month, CC to an apartment building number from 1-15, F is a floor number (1-3), and U is a unit number (1-4). There would be no spaces between the numbers and so I am having difficulty figuring out how to break up a string this way.

What I need to be able to do is create a payment book based off the input number. There is a base line cost for an apartment of $1210/month. Living in buildings 1-5 is plus $240 and living in 11-15 is minus $240. Living on the first floor is plus $20 and the third floor has is minus $20. In addition, even numbered units have a increase of $10 for fans. This comprises the monthly cost which is discounted by 50% in the months of January and July.

The end goal is to be able to create a payment book with the month spelled out, the building number, floor number, unit number, and the final price each labeled and on a separate line.

Comment: You know exactly how many characters make up each section.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to go:

1. Reject any string with `length` more than 6.
2. Reject any string `s` whose first two characters are not months,
3. Reject any string `s` whose next two characters are not building number.
4. Reject any string `s` whose next one character is not floor number.
5. Reject any string `s` whose next one character is not unit number.

Create a class `Book`  instantiate an instance and then compute the total payment. Something similar to this:

```
class Book{
    int month;
    int building_number;
    int floor_number;
    int unit_number;
    Book(String line)
    {
       // parse the line 
    }

    double computeTotalCost(){
        // retyrb the cost 
    }

    boolean validEntry(int month,int building_number,int floor_number, int unit_number)
    {
        // check if the month is between 1 and 12 
        // check if the building_number is between 1 and 15
        // check if the floor_number is between 1 and 3
        // check if the unit_number is between 1 and 5
        // If anything became incorrect : return false otherwise return true;

    }
}
```